# type &var = *ptr VS type var = *ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

Let `foo` be:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int a) {
        aa = a;
        cout << "foo built. " << aa << endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        cout << "foo DIED. " << aa << endl;
    }

    int aa;
};
```

Also, assume we have:

```
Foo* func1(){
    Foo* foo = new Foo(1);
    return foo;
}
```

Now, running this:

```
{ // <---- we have braces
    Foo obj = *func1();
}
```

yields: "foo DIED"

but running:

```
{
    Foo &obj = *func1();
}
```

does not release foo's instance.

Could you please clarify what's happening here?

Comment: It does compile and it seems that -fpermissive is present (by default in VS)

Comment: You seem to be asking what the difference is between a **reference** and an **object**.  In a very roundabout way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: *yields: "foo DIED"* -- Do you know which `foo` object died?  The one dynamically allocated is still alive.  If you want to know what object is created or destroyed, you should be ouputting the value of `this`, not just a simple message.

Comment: I am familiar with a reference, but I do not understand why this code compiles and why I get two different behaviors. @DrewDormann

Comment: Add instrumentation to `Foo`'s copy constructor and you'll see that the first makes a copy and the second doesn't.

Comment: @salehjg Both code snippets compile because they are legal code. `func1()` returns a `Foo*` pointer to a dynamic `Foo` object, which both code snippets are leaking. However, the 1st snippet is *copying* that object to another local `Foo` object, then the *copy* gets destroyed afterwards, hence the "died" message. Whereas the second snippet just takes a reference to the original `Foo` object, no copy is made, thus nothing "dies".

Comment: btw you should neither use `new` nor return the `Foo*` as raw pointer from the function.

Comment: `cout << "foo built. " << aa << " " << this << endl;`-- `cout << "foo DIED. " << aa << " " << this << endl;`.  Now you will see a mismatch of construction and destruction, all because you didn't track the creation of the copy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! Your comment answered my question completely. Post it so I can accept it.

Comment: @salehjg I can't post an answer unless the question is re-opened first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau go for it.

Comment: @DrewDormann looks like someone already beat me to it

Comment: Dumb luck. I had the answer mostly written when the question was closed. It was still cached when the question re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func1` allocates a `Foo` and returns a pointer to it. Sooner or later someone must manually `delete` that `Foo` to free up the resources it uses. Because `*func1()` dereferences the pointer before a copy of the pointer is made, the pointer is lost. Without the pointer, the object could be lost forever, preventing you from `delete`ing it when you no longer need it.

`Foo obj = *func1();` resulted in the creation of two `Foo`s. The one dynamically allocated in `func1` and another automatically allocated `Foo` named `obj` that is a copy of the `Foo` from `func1`. It is the death of `obj` when it goes out of scope that you are seeing. The `Foo` from `func1` has been lost. You have what's called a memory leak. This code cannot be fixed. It is broken, even though it's the one that looked like it worked.

`Foo &obj = *func1();` creates one `Foo`, the one from `func1`, and `obj` merely references it. When the reference goes out of scope nothing happens. You can't refer to the object as `obj` anymore, the reference is no more, but the object still exists in memory and has been leaked. But in this case while you still have `obj` referencing it, you can `delete &obj;` and free it.

```cpp
{
    Foo &obj = *func1();
    delete &obj; // get address of referenced object, then delete it.
}
```

Now you can see the object being freed.

Long-and-short: You always have to keep a live reference or pointer to a dynamically allocated object until you manually release it.